# Drag and Drop does not work in C# (Selenium Web Driver)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Is there some working code for simple drag and drop functionality?

1. Select a picture
2. Drag and Drop to a Folder
3. Release the mouse.

I have tried all possible code examples here and neither works in Visual Studio (C#).

```
WebElement firstdoc = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*@id='body']/section/div/div[5]/ul/li[1]")); 
IWebElement Fundingfolder = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='body']/section/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/di‌​v[1]/div[1]")); 
IWebElement secdoc = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='body']/section/div/div[5]/ul/li[1]/div[1]"‌​)); 
IWebElement Incomefolder = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='body']/section/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/di‌​v[2]/div[1]"));


Actions Builder = new Actions(driver); 
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)); 
Builder.MoveToElement(firstdoc); 
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)); 
Builder.ClickAndHold(firstdoc); 
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)); 
Builder.DragAndDrop(firstdoc, Fundingfolder); 
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)); 
Builder.Release(Fundingfolder).Perform(); 
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
```

Comment: Test executes and reports no error, but no action is done in Firefox UI. In this particular case there is an image (one of) to be moved into Folder

Comment: some times thread.sleep works in java instead of waits..try once

Comment: Hello, I have tried provided code in a new Visual Studio Project (C#) and it does work.

Comment: Here is complete code:

Comment: using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium;

namespace Drag_And_Drop
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1

Comment: {const string JS_DnD =
"var src=arguments[0],tgt=arguments[1];var dataTransfer={dropEff" +
"ect:'',effectAllowed:'all',files:[],items:{},types:[],setData:f" +
"unction(format,data){this.items[format]=data;this.types.append(" +
"format);},getData:function(format){return this.items[format];}," +
"clearData:function(format){}};var emit=function(event,target){v" +
"ar evt=document.createEvent('Event');evt.initEvent(event,true,f" +
"alse);evt.dataTransfer=dataTransfer;target.dispatchEvent(evt);}" +
";emit('dragstart',src);emit('dragenter',tgt);

Comment: emit('dragover',tg" +
"t);emit('drop',tgt);emit('dragend',src);";

Comment: [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {

            var driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://html5demos.com/drag");

            var ele_source = driver.FindElement(By.Id("two"));
            var ele_target = driver.FindElement(By.Id("bin"));

            // execute the drag and drop
            driver.ExecuteScript(JS_DnD, ele_source, ele_target);

        }
    }
}

Comment: I recieve next error:

Comment: Result Message: 
Test method Drag_And_Drop.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 0):

```
IWebElement drag = driver.FindElement(By.Id(id));

IWebElement drop = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xPath));

(new Actions(driver)).ClickAndHold(drag).MoveToElement(drop).DragAndDrop(drag, drop).Perform();
```